# Ajax with Node.js/Express 404

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, express

I'm building a simple login page with Node.js/Express and Ajax. The Ajax is returning a 404 not found error on call and I can't figure out why.

The Ajax call is supposed to interact with one other files, a appBackend.js which redirects all ajax calls to their proper controllers. The error is occurring on the line where I call $.ajax.

I'm guessing that it might be due to the fact that I don't have default html page to display for this api ajax call, but also can't seem to figure out how to add a default display page.

My login.js looks like this.

```
function validateUser() {
    var userID = document.getElementById('userID').value;
    var password = document.getElementById('password').value;

    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "/api/login",
        dataType: "json",
        data : {
            "user_id": userID,
            "password": password
        },
        success: function(response) {
            if (response.success) {
                // handles login success
            } else {
              
            }
        }
    });
 }
```

My appBackend.js looks like this.

```
const express = require('express');
var loginController = require("../controllers/loginController");

module.exports = function(app, dbClient) {

    app.get('/api/login', function (req, res) {
        loginController.validateUser(req, res, dbClient);
    });
}
```

My index.js code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

var frontend = require('./routes/frontend');
var MySqlClient = require('./utils/MySqlClient');
var dbClient = new MySqlClient('localhost','root','password',    
'userTable');

frontend(app, dbClient);

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Listening on port 3000!')
 });
```

Here is the error message:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/api/login?user_id=&password= 404 (Not Found)
send    @   jquery.min.js:formatted:3917
ajax    @   jquery.min.js:formatted:3679
validateUser    @   login.js:23
onclick @   login.html:50
```

and the code block that's throwing the error in ajax:

```
try {
    r.send(i.hasContent && i.data || null);
} catch (e) {
    if (o)
        throw e
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show all the express code, from index.js loading your appBackend.js, as-is where is server.listen? why are you doing dependency injection and not exporting an express router?

Comment: Added! I guess I really should be exporting express' router. I'm relatively inexperienced with express' structure and didn't know about it.

Comment: Few missing points -
1. Login route(should be POST) need to be used in index.js using app.use(appBackRoute)
2. If **dbClient** causes problem, define that in else where and export it.
3. For more hint look at - https://dev.to/nurofsun/building-simple-rest-api-with-express-js-and-mysql-140p